# Using more than one SELECT in INSERT INTO query

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to insert some values with multiple selects in the query, but its given me unknown column 'rate' in where clause error

```
   INSERT INTO oc_tax_rule (tax_class_id, tax_rate_id, based, priority)
    VALUES (
    (SELECT tax_class_id FROM oc_tax_class WHERE title LIKE '%0%'),
    (SELECT tax_rate_id FROM oc_tax_rate WHERE rate ='0'),
    'store', 1)
```

Comment: Where is the `store` coming from? the fields must be matched.

Comment: Are you trying to insert _one row_ ans substitute some values - or to insert _many rows_ as result of your `SELECT` ?

Comment: @xdazz store is a string, should be 'store'

Comment: @AlmaDo just want to insert one row

Comment: @grasshopper then - are you sure that your select's will always return one row? (my doubts are about this part: `WHERE title LIKE '%0%'` - what if there are titles, let's say, `'103'` and `'5004'` ?)

Comment: @AlmaDo yes rates and titles are unique

Comment: `unknown column 'rate'` means that table `oc_tax_rate` has no column named `rate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for this:

```
INSERT INTO oc_tax_rule (tax_class_id, tax_rate_id, based, priority)
SELECT
  (SELECT tax_class_id FROM oc_tax_class WHERE title LIKE '%0%' LIMIT 1),
  (SELECT tax_rate_id FROM oc_tax_rate WHERE rate ='0' LIMIT 1),
  'store',
  1
```

select query will return just one row, with the first and second columns that are the result of your two select query - you probably need to add a LIMIT 1 in order to make sure that only one row will be returned

Comment: So, the problem was not the syntax but that your `rate` is not unique or (more probable) that the `title LIKE '%0%'` did not return only one row.